# Prevent TextView overlap next element in Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, word-wrap

I am creating a title bar as below, the "Home" & "Drawer" icon will set visible/gone base on cases.
How could I make the text view not overlap the "Home" / "Drawer" icon??

[image]

This is what it had for my code, I manually set the text view margin to the home & drawer icon, however, when in the case that the home/drawer icon is hidden, the text long still maintain like home button appears. How can I set the text view perfectly wrap base on the space available?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_backbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/actionbar_backbutton"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/Easybook_com"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_homebutton"
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionbar_drawerbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_drawerbutton"
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_reddot"
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Comment: Check My Improved answer for your app requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Replace TextView and `use startOf and EndOf instead of LeftOf and rightOf`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/actionbar_backbutton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/actionbar_homebutton"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/Easybook_com"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: seems like it cant contain two align in one times, android:layout_toEndOf="@id/actionbar_backbutton"
android:layout_toStartOf="@id/actionbar_homebutton" it only effect start of

Answer (score 0):

you can set the TextView to be in the space between the two buttons something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_backbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_homebutton"
    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionbar_drawerbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_drawerbutton"
    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/actionbar_backbutton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/actionbar_homebutton"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@string/Easybook_com"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this make the textview start from the home button- right to left, which i want it to start from left to right

Comment: if you mean the text is right to left
you can simply change this behavior using textDirection attribute of textview 
and setting it to ltr

Answer (score 0):

Use both startOf,leftOf and endOf, rightOf in TextView.

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/actionbar_backbutton"
android:layout_toStartOf="@id/actionbar_backbutton"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/actionbar_homebutton"
android:layout_toEndOf="@id/actionbar_homebutton"
```

Comment: If you are not using some customized functionality that is not provided by Action Bar then you should use action bar, this will help you in long run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it more complex. you can also perform your requirements using like this, you just have nothing to do with your activity xml.

now, In your Activity's onCreate :

```
setTitle("Your Title");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

then, implement this two default methods for menu ,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        break;
    case R.id. actionbar_drawerbutton:
        //your code
        break;
    case R.id. actionbar_reddot:
    //your code
    break;
    }
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

now you have to create a xml file in `res/menu/menu_view.xml` like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
        android:title="Drawer Button"
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_drawerbutton"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
<item
        android:title="Red Dot"
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_reddot"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="always">
</item>

</menu>
```

this will manage all your cases. try this. I'm sure you will get better output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_backbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/actionbar_backbutton"
        android:text="@string/Easybook_com"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_homebutton"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_drawerbutton"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_reddot"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I not able to use LinearLayout to group my Image as i need to have reddot n drawerbutton to place in duplicate